# Find a lattice with exactly three congruence relations

Tags: lattice-orders

A *lattice* $L$ is a partially ordered set such that any two elements $a$ and $b$ have a least upper bound $a\lor b$ and a greatest lower bound $a\land b$.  A *congruence relation* on $L$ is an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $L$ that is compatible with the lattice operation in the sense that $a_1\sim b_1$ and $a_2\sim b_2$ implies $a_1\lor a_2\sim b_1\lor b_2$ and similarly for $\land$.

In any lattice there are always two trivial congruence relations, the congruence relation where each element is its own equivalence class (block), and at the other extreme the congruence relation with a single block.

What's an example of a lattice with exactly three congruence relations?

This is [Ex 3.40](http://books.google.com/books?id=6XJX5-zCoIQC&pg=PA61) in Graetzer (Lattice Theory: Foundation).  So it is asking to find a lattice with exactly one non-trivial congruence relation.  Any example I can think of always has at least two non-trivial congruence relations.

For example, for the linear poset with three elements $a\prec b\prec c$, one congruence relation has $a,b$ in one block and $c$ alone, and another has $a$ alone and $b,c$ together in one block.  Another example, the standard diamond lattice with four elements (consisting of all subsets of a two element set ordered by inclusion) also has two non-trivial congruence relations.

Comment: Lattices don't have to have tops or bottoms, though, so it appears we should think about unbounded ones. A screenshot of the text might be handy as well, PatrickR.

Comment: Please clarify, what are the two non-trivial congruence relations on the diamond lattice?

Comment: @vadim123 If the diamond lattice has 4 elements $0$, $a$, $b$, $1$ with $0$ as minimum element, $1$ as maximum element, and $a$ and $b$ in between and not comparable, one congruence relation has the two blocks $\{0,a\}$ and $\{b,1\}$.  The other congruence relation has the blocks $\{0,b\}$ and $\{a,1\}$.

Comment: Why wouldn't $\{0\}, \{a,b\}$ and $\{1\}$ be a congruence? You're gluing the middle pieces together and preserving order.

Comment: @user69810 Because $a\sim b$ implies $a\lor a\sim b\lor a$, that is, $a\sim 1$.

Comment: In general, each congruence class of a congruence relation on a lattice is a sublattice, i.e., closed under $\lor$ and $\land$.

Comment: I see. If you tried the lattice with $a$, $b$ and $c$ in between $0$ and $1$ you'd have too many relations.

Comment: You may be on to something.  It seems that the lattice $M_3$ with 5 elements $a$, $b$, $c$ and $0$, $1$ that you mention has only the trivial congruences.  So maybe a variation of this would have a single non-trivial congruence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: A lattice with a single nontrivial congruence.]

**Proof:** The elements of the 
diamond right under the top must be either separated or in a single class,
because diamond has only trivial congruences.

If they are in a single class, then $d\sim b$ implies $a\sim 0$ and $b\sim e$
implies $c\sim 0$. Thus, $a\sim c$ and $0\sim a\sim a\vee c=1$ and this clearly implies that the congruence is trivial.

Similarly, it is easy to see that $a,b,c$ must be separated, otherwise some pair of elements in the diamond is not separated and we have a trivial congruence again.

So the only *possible* pairs we can relate are $a\sim d$, $b\sim 0$ $e\sim c$.
It is easy to see that any of them forces the other two, so we are left with the single equivalence that is a candidate for a congruence, namely
$\{\{0,b\},\{a,d\},\{c,e\},\{f\},\{1\}\}$.

The remaining tedious checking that this is indeed a congruence is omitted.

Comment: Diamond has two nontrivial congruences.

Comment: @IttayWeiss There is probably some misunderstanding. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#/media/File:M3_1xyz0.svg) is the diamond lattice, it is a standard lattice theoretic term.

Comment: I always thought that this is simply $M_3$ while the diamond lattice refers to just the four element lattice. In any case, certainly $M_3$ has only trivial congruences.

Comment: @IttayWeiss It is true that not everybody always refers to $M_3$ as ``the diamond''. However, Birkoff and Mac Lane did call $M_3$ diamond in [their book](https://books.google.sk/books?id=L6FENd8GHIUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=birkhoff+mac+lane+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR0brulbfhAhVBwcQBHbpGDpAQ6AEIKjAA#v=snippet&q=diamond&f=false). Birkhoff then refrained from this term in his monograph "Lattice theory". However, George Grätzer uses "diamond" in his books and he is The Person With Most Authority In Lattice Theory nowadays.

Comment: @IttayWeiss OTOH, I have never heard anybody to refer to $M_2$ as ``the diamond''.

Comment: I'm very happy to accept Grätzer's authority :)

Answer (score 6):

Found the following example:
[image: lattice with a single non-trivial congruence]

The only non-trivial congruence relation has $a$ and $b$ in one block and all the other elements alone.

Comment: I think this is the smallest example.